# how to query (oracle) database table structure in C# / (ADO?).NET 2.0

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracle10g

I want to get table metadata for all table columns. Like type string(varchar2)/int/float/datetime and length for strings etc.

Cheers! -Matti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all tables that you can access :

```
select * from all_tab_columns
```

For all tables in the current schema :

```
select * from user_tab_columns
```

This is specific to Oracle, but there is a more generic way to retrieve schema information : the [`DbConnection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.getschema.aspx) method :

```
schema_owner = "the_owner"; // or null
table_name = "the_table"; // or null
column_name = "the_column"; // or null
DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { schema_owner, table_name, column_name });
```

The resulting table contains all available column information that matches the criteria.

For a list of all available schema metadata, you can call `GetSchema` with `DbMetaDataCollectionNames.MetaDataCollections` as a parameter.

Comment: thanks a lot! i didn't even say that I was gonna use that generic class anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.getschema.aspx) method of the [OracleConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx) class.